# Problems reindexing a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I have a df labeled df_2 that is missing some dates and I'd like to reindex the dataframe to include all dates in the range of the index and have 0's where no data is available. When I use the following code I end up getting a dataframe with all 0's instead of populated rows where date is already available in the index and rows with 0's where date is not available. Note that I also tried using date_range() to reindex the df and that produced the same erroneous df with all 0's:

```
df_2.head()

DATE        TOTAL_SALES  TOTAL_TRAFFIC
2018-01-02        36904         4974.0
2018-01-03        33303         4610.0
2018-01-04        29485         4493.0
2018-01-05        33017         4246.0
2018-01-06        44762         5081.0

idx = pd.period_range(min(df_2.index), max(df_2.index))
df_3 = df_2.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

df_3.head()

            TOTAL_SALES  TOTAL_TRAFFIC
2018-01-02            0            0.0
2018-01-03            0            0.0
2018-01-04            0            0.0
2018-01-05            0            0.0
2018-01-06            0            0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DatetimeIndex` is not a `PeriodIndex`. You should use `date_range` instead of `period_range`:

```
idx = pd.date_range(df_2.index.min(), df_2.index.max())
df_3 = df_2.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
print(df3.head())

# Output:
            TOTAL_SALES  TOTAL_TRAFFIC
2018-01-02        36904         4974.0
2018-01-03        33303         4610.0
2018-01-04        29485         4493.0
2018-01-05        33017         4246.0
2018-01-06        44762         5081.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Corralien! I'm still having the same issue though where the dataframe contains only zeros...

Comment: Can you share your data file?